# Custom Android App for TurtleBot

Tags: turtlebot, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I am really new to ROS but currently I am required to learn how to develop a custom Android App for TurtleBot. The thing is, I followed [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android) and got kinda lost as I have very less exposure on Linux. The commands used in the tutorial and the instructions are kinda new and advanced to me.

My question is, is it possible to develop such Android App for TurtleBot using Eclipse in Windows or Linux environment, though I prefer Windows environment. If so, would someone mind giving me some step-by-step guidance?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43904/custom-android-app-for-turtlebot/) by [steven7](https://answers.ros.org/users/3213/steven7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not maintain the Applications Platform and have not used it myself. So, I can't really help there.

As far as rosjava goes, there are many tutorials for development:

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html

But, there are none for Windows. I do know that there are many Windows developers using rosjava though.

Developing with rosjava on Android is also documented:

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/index.html

Gradle works on Windows, so the steps should be similar. If you document your steps some place, I'm sure others would appreciate it.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Developing ROS Android apps is difficult, because rosjava is still evolving rapidly. If you're going to do rosjava development, get to know Daemon Kohler, the lead developer for it.

In theory, all of the individual tools for ROS and Android development should work on Windows, but in practice I think it will be quite difficult to set up. If you have an Ubuntu Linux machine available, start there first.

I'm not sure where the Eclipse integration with the rosjava tools is; the last time I used rosjava, all of the development was done through command-line tools. I was able to get Eclipse to do what I wanted, but that was 8 months ago, and I know a lot has changed.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-09-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1